# Why did Cobb and Ariadne jump off the building?

Tags: inception

At the end of Inception Cobb and Ariandne jump of a skyscraper after meeting Mal.

Was there any point to this? A jump is supposed to return you to that level of the dream: the bus hitting the water causes them to return to the bus. So what's the point of having a kick in limbo? They're not asleep and there's nothing to wake up from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dying in Limbo seems to take you back up to the previous dream level, without the need for a kick. The entire point of the movie is that when Cobb and Mal first encountered Limbo, they were unaware/unsure how to get out. They chose to stay inside until Cobb finally convinced Mal ***using inception*** that they should kill themselves together.

It's this method that Cobb and Mal use to exit Limbo and it's this method that Cobb and Saito use to leave Limbo at the end of the film:

> Cobb turns to Ariadne, who is pointing Cobb’s gun.
>
> **COBB:** *What’re you doing?*
>
> **ARIADNE:** *Improvising.*
>
> She KICKS Fischer off the roof– AIMS again at Mal–
>
> Fischer DROPS as the sky LIGHTS UP WITH ELECTRICITY– Fischer SCREAMS,
>   then GASPS, no longer falling, and we are– [in the next level up again]

and

> **COBB:** *Yes. And to take a leap of faith.*
>
> As Saito-san listens to Cobb, **he looks at the GUN on the table between
>   them…**
>
> **COBB:** *Come back and we’ll be young men together again.*

Comment: What about the sedative? The whole point of the kick is to avoid the fact that if they die under the sedative, they don't wake up. Is there any reason to believe that the sedative losses this effect in limbo?

Comment: @FreshWaterTaffy - Yes, the fact is that four people die in limbo under the sedative (Fischer, Ariadne, Cobb and Saito). Two return to the dream layer they just left (Fischer and Ariadne) and two evidently return to the waking world. That seems pretty conclusive proof that limbo is the lowest layer possible and that if you die in limbo, the sedative has no obvious effect.

Comment: I guess this is probably the best answer that makes sense....

Comment: although they clearly wake up from limbo before they hit the ground, meaning the writers intended it as a kick.